# Call Method from View on Button click without reload

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I haven't found a solution for my problem.
I am using asp.net mvc. In my View I am  trying to call a Method, on a Buttonclick.
This is how the button looks like at the moment

```
 <button type="button" id="@openButtonID" data-loading-text=" öffnen..." class="btn btn-primary" autocomplete="off" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Open", "Home", new {index =i} )'" disabled="@notConnected">
```

So every time I am clicking the button the website reloads itself.
At the website there is a camera stream which disappears for some seconds during the refresh. Now I have the task to avoid this, so the stream can been seen during the whole time. I have tried to call the method via Razor like this:

```
<button type="button" id="@openButtonID" data-loading-text=" öffnen..." class="btn btn-primary" autocomplete="off" onclick="@{( (GateControl.Controllers.HomeController)this.ViewContext.Controller ).Open( i );}" disabled="@notConnected">
```

But this just calls the Method if the view is loaded. As I tried this I set the return of the method to void.
Also I tried it like it is described like in [this](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ajax-get-and-post-calls-to.html). Either the website is reloaded or I wasn't able to get in the method. I also tried several code snippets from stack overflow, but it wasn't working.

This is how the Method looks like

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public void Open( int index )
{

    //some code

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already tried something with jQuery I suppose you use the library. 
What you can do is to bind a click event to your button and inside that to make a GET ajax call. 
You can use a "data-" attribute in your button to have your url generated on server and available on client.

```
<button id="button-id" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text=" öffnen..."  data-url="@Url.Action("Open", "Home", new {index =i} )" disabled="@notConnected" autocomplete="off">
```

This should do it:

```
   $("#button-id").click(function(){
        var url = $("#button-id").data("url");
        $.get(url , function(result) {
           //do something with the result if you ever need to
        });
    });
```

This way you won't get the page refresh. You could also give us a little more details about that server method and what it does, maybe it needs some changes also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code I am using

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<button type="button" id="@openButtonID" data-loading-text=" öffnen..." class="btn btn-primary" autocomplete="off" data-url="@Url.Action("Open", "Home" , new {index=i+1} )" disabled="@notConnected">
                            Öffnen
                        </button><br /><br />
                          <script type="text/jscript">
    $("#@openButtonID").click(function () {
        var url = $("#@openButtonID").data("url");
        $.get(url, function (result) {
            //do something with the result if you ever need to
        });
    });
                        </script>
```